# Analytics Adding Allow Anchor to JS

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I would like to set my campaign tracking to allow # instead of ? using _setAllowAnchor(true)

However, I have yet to find an example of the GA javascript that looks quite like mine (from html5boilerplate). How would I add add _setAllowAnchor(true) to the below javascript?

```
<script>
   var _gaq = [['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-X'], ['_trackPageview']];
   (function(d, t) {
    var g = d.createElement(t),
        s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
    g.async = true;
    g.src = ('https:' == location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
   })(document, 'script');
  </script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var _gaq = [['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-X'], ['_setAllowAnchor', true], ['_trackPageview']];
```

The main thing to note here is that it needs to come before the _trackPageview, as that is the actual trigger for the code.